# Idle device and inactive phone consuming too much battery

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery, charging

I just bought a brand new Zonda A450 with Android 4.4. I was quite surprised when the battery started to drain too fast. Even taking a photo with flash could take 3% of the battery instantly. From what I see, the device being idle and the phone being inactive take 50% of the battery!

> [image: screenshot]

I searched in Google on how to optimize the OS, remove useless apps and widgets, etc., but I just saw a slight improvement.

What I can do to reduce the percent of battery used? Since these two aren't apps, I couldn't find an answer on Google. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The battery display of Android 4.4 was pretty bad and imprecise.  This was improved in the successor versions as well as the battery saving possibilities. If the device is new try to get an update to Android 5. If it is not available they sold you a shopkeeper...

Comment: @Robert You do recommend to upgrade to android 5?

Comment: When it comes to battery saving you should upgrade to the latest version available. Generally the battery saving improvements are getting better and better with each Android version.

Answer (score 0):

I found what caused the excessive battery drain was, i changed the Preferred network setting to just use G3(WCDMA)(or whatever network your carrier uses) instead of the auto/global setting it has by default, now the inactive phone drains 28% of the battery, better than before